# Probability Revision

Tags: probability

An urn contains $2$ black balls and $3$ white balls. Two balls are drawn at random from the urn. Find the probability that both balls are black.

**My approach towards this problem:-**

No. of black balls = 2

No. of white balls = 3

Total no. of balls = 5

2 balls are drawn at random

P(E) = ($2$C2)/$5$C2 = $1/10$

is this the right answer? If not, please help. My textbook says the correct answer is $3/10$.
I can't figure it how..

Comment: The tag (revision) is being removed. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11694/whats-up-with-the-revision-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textbook's answer appears to be wrong.